# Can I compare the average coefficients of variation?

Tags: coefficient-of-variation

I have two datasets.  The first shows a populations choices for mode of transport (3 modes) in 6 different areas.  The second shows the same populations responses to concerning attributes (13 attributes) in their public transport experiences across the same 6 different areas. I would like to compare how varied each dataset is.

For the first dataset I find the coefficient of variation for each **mode** of transport across the 6 different areas. I am left with **3** coefficients of variation.

For the second dataset I find the coefficient of variation for each **attribute** acrosss the 6 different areas.  I am left with **13** different coefficients of variation.

Could I take the average of the 3 coefficients of variation and compare it to the average of the 13 coefficients of variation as a means of comparing the variance between the two datasets?

i.e. Dataset 1 has a low average coefficient of variation, while Dataset 2 has a high average coefficient of variation, therefore, Dataset 2 is more varied than Dataset 1.

My knowledge of statistics is quite basic and I'm sure my use of language reflects that.  Let me know if you need any clarification.

Thanks!